# Is it possible to find this limit

Tags: limits

One student of mine asked me to find
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^nke^{-\frac kn}$$

I thought about a Riemann sum but it is not.
I tried, in vain, to write it as a derivative of certain sum .

I thank you in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there were an extra factor of $\frac1n$, the expression would be
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n ke^{-k/n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n \frac kn e^{-k/n} = \int_0^1 xe^{-x}\,dx = 1-\frac2e,
$$
where the middle equality holds because of right-hand Riemann sums.

In our case, therefore, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n ke^{-k/n} = \bigg( \lim_{n\to\infty} n \bigg) \bigg( \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n ke^{-k/n} \bigg) = \infty\cdot\bigg(1-\frac2e\bigg)=\infty.
$$

Indeed, in highsight, we could simply note that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n ke^{-k/n} \ge \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n \sum_{k=n/2}^n ke^{-k/n}\ge \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n \sum_{k=n/2}^n \frac n2 e^{-1} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac n{4e} = \infty.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. appreciate.

Comment: @Greg Martin: A doubt. Suppose we have the same situation but the integral is $0$, is that an indeterminate form? I think yes because the integral is a limit, so if I get $\lim_{n \to \infty} (n \cdot A)$ where $A=0$ is the result of the evaluation of an integral I can't conclude that the entire product of limits is $0$ because it is an indeterminate form. Moreover I can't even split the limit in the product of two limits because it is possible only when there isn't an indeterminate form. Am I correct? Thanks.

Comment: That's correct, I think—in that situation one would have to understand the specifics more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

For the limit itself, it is sure that the Rieman sum is from far the simplest way to get it.

The problem is interesting also for the partial sums and their asymptotics.

Let $x=e^{-1/n}$
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n ke^{-\frac kn}=\sum_{k=1}^nkx^k=x \sum_{k=1}^nkx^{k-1}=x\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx^{k}\right)'=\frac{(n x-n-1) x^{n+1}+x}{(1-x)^2}$$
$$S_n=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}} (-n+e-1)+n}{e \left(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)^2}$$ Now, using Taylor series for large values of $n$
$$S_n=\left(1-\frac{2}{e}\right) n^2+\frac{n}{2
   e}-\frac{1}{12}+\frac{3-\frac{2}{e}}{720 n^2}O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\frac {S_n}n=\left(1-\frac{2}{e}\right) n+\frac{1}{2
   e}-\frac{1}{12n}+\frac{3-\frac{2}{e}}{720 n^3}O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you so much. A impressive answer.